Norm estimate of self-adjoint
Let $X_1, X_2\in\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$ be self-adjoint with $\vert X_1\vert+\vert X_2\vert\leq 1$ where $\vert X\vert:=\sqrt{X^*X}$. Does it imply $\Vert X_1+X_2\Vert\leq 1$ and $\Vert X_1-X_2\Vert\leq 1?$
Comments: I was trying to prove it using polar decomposition but not able to conclude this in affirmative. Neither, I am getting counter example.
Your comments are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

@daw Sorry, how is it following? $\vert X_1\vert+\vert X_2\vert\leq 1$ does not imply that $\Vert\vert X_1\vert\Vert+\Vert \vert X_2\vert\Vert\leq 1$.

David's answer is certainly more elementary, but you might be interested to know that there is a version of the triangle inequality for the modulus in von Neumann algebras: For every pair $(x,y)\in M\times M$ there exist isometries $v$, $w$ such that $\lvert x+y\rvert\leq v\lvert x\rvert v^\ast+ w\lvert y\rvert w^\ast$.

This is true. Indeed, as $X_i$ is self-adjoint, $-|X_i| \leq X_i \leq |X_i|$ for each $i$. Thus,
$$-1 \leq -|X_1| - |X_2| \leq X_1 + X_2 \leq |X_1| + |X_2| \leq 1$$
So $\|X_1 + X_2\| \leq 1$. That $\|X_1 - X_2\| \leq 1$ can be proved by changing $X_2$ to $-X_2$.
